# Why is a Dirac operator involutive only if the curvature and torsion are in the image of the kernel of the symbol under exterior multiplication?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, vector-bundles, fiber-bundles, connections

I am trying to understand the classic paper by Atiyah, Hitchin, and Singer

https://www.jstor.org/stable/79638

and I'm getting stuck on part of the proof of proposition 3.1.  The proposition is determining the conditions for involutivity of the vector bundle $V(\bar{D})$ associated with a differential operator $\bar{D}=\sigma\nabla$, spanned by one forms $\theta_i$ and $\sigma_i$.  In particular, it says that $d \theta_i$ and $d \sigma_i^\nu$ are sections of $V_2$ only if the curvature of $\nabla$ and $D_1 \sigma_i^\nu$ are sections of $V(S_2)$.  Here $V_2$ is the image of $V(\bar{D})$ under exterior multiplication, and $V(S_2)$ is the image of the kernel of $\sigma$ under exterior multiplication.  I don't understand why it is possible to conclude that the curvature and $D_1 \sigma_i^\nu$ must be sections of $V(S_2)$ instead of the presumably larger space $V_2$ (spanned by $V(S_2)$ in addition to two forms of the form $\theta_i\wedge \alpha_i$ for any $\alpha_i$), it is not really explained and not obvious to me.

Comment: I think it might have something to do with the curvature being in the vertical subbundle, or something of that nature.  I am still thinking about it.

Comment: I think I mean that the curvature is in the horizontal subbundle.  I'm still not sure about $(D_1\sigma_i)^{\nu}$ though.